# How do you find the limit as $x$ approaches infinity of $x! / a^x$ for some integer $a$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

The limit as $n$ approaches infinity of the following functions diverges:

- $n! / a^n$
- $n! / n^a$

For any fixed integer $a$. How can I show this?

EDIT: The original question was the second bullet point; however I really meant to type the first bullet.

Comment: One way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Use $x!\geq2^{x-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

By ratio test

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{a^n}{n!}}=0$$

thus the series $\sum\frac{a^n}{n!}$ is convergent and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=0$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n!}{a^n}=+\infty$$

For the second, it is easy to prove by induction that

$n!\geq 2^{n-1}$ and

$$\frac{n!}{n^a}\geq \frac{2^{n-1}}{n^a}$$

as the exponential is faster than the polynomial, the limit is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{\large{n! \over a^{n}}:\ ?\quad \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty}$.
  \begin{align}
  {n! \over a^{n}} & \sim {\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over a^{n}} =
  \root{2\pi}n^{1/2} \pars{n \over a\expo{}}^{n} \to \infty
  \end{align}

  ---
- $\ds{\large{n! \over n^{a}}:\ ?\quad \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty}$.

\begin{align}
\mbox{Similarly,}\quad
{n! \over n^{a}} & \sim {\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over n^{a}} =
\root{2\pi}n^{1/2}n^{n - a + 1/2}\expo{-n} \to \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

For $x$ and $a$ integers with $x>a$ we can write

$$\frac{x!}{x^a}=\left(\frac{x}{x}\frac{x-1}{x}\frac{x-2}{x}\cdots \frac{x-a+1}{x}\right)(x-a)!$$

---

If $x$ is real and $a$ is an integer, then

$$x!=\int_0^\infty t^{x}e^{-t}\,dt$$

Now, apply L'Hospital's Rule $a$ times.

Comment: My apologies, I actually typed the exponential incorrectly, the original I do understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $a$;

$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\ldots (n-(a-1)(n-a)(n-(a+1))\ldots 3.2.1$

So we have $\dfrac{n!}{n^a}=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\ldots (n-(a-1)(n-a)(n-(a+1))\ldots 3.2.1}{n^a}$

$=(1-\dfrac{1}{n})(1-\dfrac{2}{n})\ldots \times f(n)$  where $f(n)>1$ and the product $ \to \infty $as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, both the numerator and denominator of $\frac {n!}{a^n}$ have $n$ factors.   As $n$ gets large, most of the factors in the numerator are much larger than $a$, while all the factors in the denominator are $a$, so the numerator grows faster and the fraction diverges.

To be more rigorous, note that for $n=a^2$, you can pair the factors of $n!$ as $(1,a^2), (2,a^2-1), (3,a^2-2), \ldots (\frac 12a^2-1, \frac 12a^2)$ and the product of each pair is greater than $a^2$, so the whole product is greater than $(a^2)^{a^2/2}=a^{(a^2)}$ and the fraction is greater than $1$.  Each upward step in $n$ now multiplies the fraction by something greater than $\frac {a^2}a$, so the fraction diverges.

You can also use Stirling's approximation for the factorial, that $n! \approx \frac {n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ and find $\frac {n!}{a^n} \gt \frac {n^n}{(ae)^n}=\left(\frac n{ae} \right)^n$  which clearly diverges as $n$ gets greater than $ae$